# Creating index using dynamic SQL

Tags: postgresql, index, trigger, postgresql-9.4, hstore

I have following code for creating gist index

```
CREATE INDEX web_stats_project_107_properties_crosspromo_gist_idx 
    ON web_stats_project_107 USING gist (properties) 
    WHERE properties @> '"block_level_0"=>"cerber-head"'::hstore  
        AND properties @> '"block_level_1"=>"head"'::hstore 
        AND properties @> '"block_level_2"=>"cross-news"'::hstore
        AND properties ? 'block_level_5'::text
        AND (NOT (properties ? 'block_level_6'::text));
```

It works smoothly when I use it directly.

But I need to use it inside the trigger with some variables. And here the problem comes.

I tried two variants of code:

```
createIndex := 'CREATE INDEX idx_'||Fulltable_name||'_properties_crosspromo_gist 
ON public.'||Fulltable_name||' USING gist (properties) 
WHERE properties @> '"block_level_0"=>"cerber-head"'::hstore 
AND ...;
```

and

```
createIndex := 'CREATE INDEX idx_'||Fulltable_name||'_properties_crosspromo_gist 
ON public.'||Fulltable_name||' USING gist (properties) 
WHERE (((((properties @> '"block_level_0"=>"cerber-head"'::hstore) 
AND ...;
```

And I even can't apply it for DB because of syntax error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "=>" LINE 32: ...perties) WHERE
>   (((((properties @> '"block_level_0"=>"cerber-...

or

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE" LINE 32:
>   createIndex := 'createIndex := 'CREATE INDEX idx...

Seems I have to escape some symbols with some characters.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: You are still open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
createIndex := 'CREATE INDEX idx_'
    || Fulltable_name
    || '_properties_crosspr_gist ON public.'
    || Fulltable_name
    || ' 
    USING gist (properties) 
    WHERE properties @> $$"block_level_0"=>"cerber-head"$$::hstore 
      AND properties @> $$"block_level_1"=>"head"$$::hstore 
      AND properties @> $$"block_level_2"=>"cross-news"$$::hstore 
      AND properties ? $$block_level_5$$::text 
      AND NOT properties ? $$block_level_6$$::text';
```

Comment: Please check what the `format()` function does and use it.  Gives a much cleaner feeling.